# How to make an element go back to being noneditable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, user-input, contenteditable

I'm trying to make a user-made list and it does most of what it's supposed to. One thing I noticed, though, was that when I click the edit button on one of the list items, it remains editable for the entirety of the session. I want it to stop being editable when the user clicks on another element other than that edit button or the targeted list item.

HTML:

```
<ul id="todoList">
  <li v-for="item in items" contenteditable="false" id="item">{{item}}
    <div></div>
      <button id="editButton" contenteditable="false" onclick="edit(event)">Edit</button>
```

JS:

```
var editB=document.getElementById("editButton");
var tdList=document.getElementById("todoList");
var listItem = document.getElementById("item");

function edit(event) {
  var button = event.target,
    li = button.parentNode;
  li.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't using jQuery, you could listen for `mousedown` events on the todo list and reset every "editable" item unless you're clicking the button with `node.addEventListener`:

```
var editB=document.getElementById("editButton");
var tdList=document.getElementById("todoList");
var listItem = document.getElementById("item");

function contentEditable(node) {
  node.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
}

function edit(event) {
  var button = event.target,
    li = button.parentNode;
  contentEditable(li);
}

tdList.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var editable = document.querySelectorAll("li.item");
  var target = event.target;
  var id = target.getAttribute("id");

  editable.forEach(function(li){
    li.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  })

 if(id == "editButton") {edit(event)}
 if(id == "item") {contentEditable(target)}
})
```

You also need a way to query for "currently editable" things. I added a selector to the li, and removed the `contenteditable` attribute from the button:

```
<ul id="todoList">
  <li v-for="item in items" class="item" contenteditable="false" id="item">Item
    <div></div>
    <button id="editButton">Edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle here to try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/bomatson/ny1c0j0z/1/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: You can't edit... Click on list and try to type something, you are setting `contenteditable` to false.

Comment: Good call! Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's working like you expected. You can click outside text or on button to disable editing.

```js
var editB = document.getElementById("editButton");
var tdList = document.getElementById("todoList");
var listItem = document.getElementById("item");
var inEdit = false;

function edit(event) {
  var button = event.target,
    li = button.parentNode;
  inEdit = !inEdit;
  li.setAttribute("contenteditable", inEdit);
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  if (event.target.getAttribute == "editButton" || !event.target.hasAttribute("contenteditable")) {
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable='true']");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      lists[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="todoList">
  <li v-for="item in items" contenteditable="false" id="item">{{item}}
    <button id="editButton" onclick="edit(event)">Edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```